# Task Scheduler Powershell won't write to file

Tags: powershell, logging, permissions, server, scheduled-tasks

I have a powershell script designed for logging that is triggered and run through a scheduled task. The problem is the script will not write to file when run in this way. If i run it through cmd it works perfectly. I have tried giving the script highest privileges and I am passing the exact location of the log-file as an argument when I run the script. Neither have solved the issue. Please can someone help? See code:

```
Param([string]$inputPath, [string]$logfilelocation)

$i=0

$paths = Get-Content $inputPath;  #Text file with list of file paths to monitor
$global:Logfile = $logfilelocation

foreach ($path in $paths)  
{ 
    $filter = '*.*'  # You can enter a wildcard filter here. 

    # In the following line, you can change 'IncludeSubdirectories to $false if     
    # required to disable subfolder monitoring.  
    $fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $path, $filter -Property @{IncludeSubdirectories = $false; NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName,     LastWrite'}  

    # Here, all four events are registerd. You need only subscribe to events that you need: 
    #File Created
    Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier "$i+FileCreated" -Action { 
        $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name 
        $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType 
        $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated
        $username = F:\FTU-E2\PsLoggedon.exe -l 
        Write-Host "The file '$name' was $changeType by $username" -fore green 
        Out-File -FilePath $global:Logfile -Append -InputObject "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp by $username" -Force
    } 

    ++$i
}

while($true){
    start-sleep -second 5
}
```

Command:

`Powershell.exe Add arguments: -ExecutionPolicy Bypass F:\FTU-E2\Scripts\monitor.ps1 -inputPath F:\FTU-E2\RejectPaths.txt -logfilelocation "F:\FTU-E2\Log.txt"`

Comment: Please include the full command, inc. arguments, you use when calling your script via the Task Scheduler.

Comment: Is the F: drive a mapped drive or a local disk?

Comment: Program/Script: Powershell.exe Add arguments: -ExecutionPolicy Bypass F:\FTU-E2\Scripts\monitor.ps1 -inputPath F:\FTU-E2\RejectPaths.txt -logfilelocation "F:\FTU-E2\Log.txt"

Comment: f is a local disk.

Comment: Troubleshooting what's going wrong in a script run by a Scheduled Task can be a pain.  You might make some progress by using Start-Transcript at the beginning of the script, and this will allow you to add some debugging messages that get logged.  Use out-host instead of write-host so that messages will go to the transcript.

Comment: It does work under the system account, but you have to remove the `$username = C:\temp\PsLoggedon.exe -l` line and all references to $username.  When it's running under the SYSTEM account, PSLoggedOn is probably displaying the license agreement and waiting on user input.

Comment: Hi Thank-you a combination of using start-transcript and using -accepteula with the ps-loggedon as mentioned in the answer below worked. Thank-you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the task is set to run under the SYSTEM account, or really any account other than your account, it is hanging up at the `$username = F:\FTU-E2\PsLoggedon.exe -l` because PsLoggedon is waiting for a user to accept the EULA, which appears the first time a user runs it on a machine.

You can bypass the EULA with the `-accepteula` command:

```
$username = C:\temp\PsLoggedon.exe -l -accepteula
```

Once I made this change, it ran fine whether the task was set to run with my account or the SYSTEM account.

Also, you can remove the infinite loop at the bottom of the script and use the `-NoExit` switch on the PowerShell command so that the process isn't ended.

```
 -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoExit ...
```